# Extracting first n elements from a list of vectors to a new list

Tags: r, list

I have a list with multiple vectors such as

```
List1<- list(v1=sample(1:100,150,replace=TRUE),v2=sample(1:100,150,replace=TRUE),v3=sample(1:100,150,replace=TRUE),v4=sample(1:100,150,replace=TRUE))
```

The output is something like

```
$v1
  [1]  37  20  26  46  70  70  46  58  99  45  33  51  54  71   1  46  70  39  97  50  68  15   3  78  99  85  26
 [28]  41  49  64   1  49  91  52  23  67  53  96  79  64   7  21  10  56  42  36   4  32  27  23   8   3  74  58
 [55]  58  78  51  59  24  88  69  31  58  95  19  27  65  34  16  66  56   7  68  85  43  44  34  18  34  25  54
 [82]  84  69   9  35  53  19 100  28  31  66  64  24  73  39  28  70  47  57  17  67  27  54  79  15  19  23  60
[109]  60  84  65  98  47  57  10  38  65  48  31  23  12  94  81  16 100  45  71  61  24   6  33 100  22  84  74
[136]  92  43  49  41  59  57  40  22  35  78  46  83  27  65  20

$v2
  [1]  97  45  47  23  32  88  45  93  88  64 100  21  85  70  99  70  59  54  20  45  62  63  91  42  24  74  20
 [28]  29   3  67  96  31   1  11  50  24  32  14  27  41  73  89  92  55  45  83  77  34  94  51  80  93  52   2
 [55]  73  51  63  56  78  58  48  91  38  97  28  53  94  60  45  24   2  74  17  38  40  49  61  81  59  29  80
 [82]  60  47   9  71  37   9  10  68  98   6  34  52  24  36  41  28  37  46  75  63  10  30  69  23 100  29  83
[109]  88  60  87  53  51  94  31  48  17  71  14  23  12  71  21  47  79  23  96  42  95   2  16  81  72  64  15
[136]  28  40  40  77  13  99  87  29  95  64  18  46  49  25  74

$v3
  [1]  67  22  45  78  79  92  24  25  22  95  67  91   4  72  37  49  87  32  80   2  54  96  48  79  39  47  75
 [28]   3  24  37  93  64  97  83  50  85  61  93  78  53  35  77  14  12  70  74  24  54  26  73  33  28  19  35
 [55]  87  26  62  85  29  62  21  65  27  64   8  67  76  86  74  80  68  66  34  97  83  11  30  69  20  79  90
 [82]  36  18   7  58   9  32  88  64  22  76  99  71  62  10  62  50  70  79  37  73 100   4  47  17  96  79  29
[109]  55  58  79  46  45  81  57  74  21  69  86  60  21   3  79  87   8  88  79  65  82  72  36  97   1  73  82
[136]  29  97  81  88  42  35  10  98  66  17  76  85  84  31  51

$v4
  [1]  66  15  87  78   6   2  57  57  21  46  97  83  70  56   2  92   2  57  89  69  58   9  24  89  65  48  92
 [28]  87  91 100  91  99  21  16  26  83  38  90  57  14   5  74  72  33  52  59  92  85   8  80  53  82  41  91
 [55]  69  33   8  14  10  25  88  35  21  48  60  81  57  13  16  69  50  30  16   1  89  73  17   3  46  86  71
 [82]  75  16  91  73  25  92  93  54  59  59  27  25  51   9  27  18  74  66   5  51  60  63  17  94  25  22 100
[109]   4  95  57  89  56  26  36  52  40  74  31  46  16  18   9  27  51  87  74  50  28  87  85  52  34  76  31
[136]  56  84  25  91  33  98  80   2  30  49  90  23  21   2  26
```

I want to extract the first 6 elements of each of the vectors, and save it to a new list, such that the output may look like

```
$v1
[1]  37  20  26  46  70  70

$v2
  [1]  97  45  47  23  32  88

$v3
  [1]  67  22  45  78  79  92

$v4
  [1]  66  15  87  78   6   2
```

I have tried `sapply(List1,head,6)`, but this is not the output I was looking for.

Comment: Try `lapply(List1, head, 6)` or `lapply(List1, function(x) x[1:6])`

Comment: `lapply(List1, "[", 1:6)` would work, too.

Comment: Voting to close as typo as it seems OP tried `sapply` but needed `lapply`. (Or needed to add the argument `simplify = FALSE` to `sapply`.)

Comment: `sapply` is a good try but @GregorThomas is right.

Comment: The `l` in `lapply` is *list*. If you want a list output, use `lapply`! (The `s` in `sapply` is *simplify*, it creates a list and then attempts to simplify it to a vector or matrix or other more compact structure.)

Comment: @pkha write up which of the above you chose as an answer and accept it. This is an issue/confusion that comes up (often, and has representative 'duplicates'), but these comments also represent useful info for those learning when to apply what, and accepted answers are referenced more than duplicates, so you'll be helping others. My opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn’t find the accept answer button. But yes I should have used ‘’’lapply’’’ instead of ‘’’sapply’’’ , so everyone is correct, but I went with @AndreWildberg because it was the closest to what I was trying. Thank you all.